# Can a Heroku app use different/multiple ports?

Tags: python, email, heroku, port

Web services on Heroku normally use the PORT environment variable, but I want to run a custom mail server on Heroku. So I need to expose 2 ports, preferably 110 and 25, but I can live with alternatives. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dotcloud allows this: https://github.com/pepijndevos/Twemail

Answer (score 3):

No, just running some quick tests against the heroku proxy (proxy.heroku.com) I can only make connections to ports 80 and 443. Being as heroku don't provide any POP/SMTP it doesn't make sense for them to have those ports open I'm afraid.

Comment: But you can Git and SSH into the server, right? And then I found these 2 pages, one doing weird ec2 stuff, the other connecting on port 5000. http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/external-services http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/oneoff-admin-ps#timeout_awaiting_process

Comment: ec2 stuff detailed there is outbound from heroku not inbound.

Comment: `$ telnet rendezvous.heroku.com 5000` is an inbound connection, right? Although technically, it doesn't need to be a Heroku app.

Comment: Yes, that's an inbound connection.

Answer (score 0):

Custom mail server? Nope.

Heroku's mail services? Yes, check out the "Add-On" link for cloudmailin, mailgun and sendgrid. Basic service is free (they still want your credit-card and hope you exceed free quota).