# heroku different port for Rest service

Tags: heroku

I have a java application which exposes a port to receive data from outside. I'm wondering how to make heroku also expose this port? I now expose the port to 8170, when I tried to connect it, I always get couldn't connect to host error. I tried to change the $PORT variable, but it always says it fails to bind to port. Could anyone help me on this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Per [Can a Heroku app use different/multiple ports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107748/can-a-heroku-app-use-different-multiple-ports), you can only use the default ports of 80 and 443 for apps on Heroku.

Changing `$PORT` is unlikely to help; this is the mechanism Heroku uses to tell your app what port to run on within the server; it then puts a proxy between the real network port and your application.

If you really, really must expose HTTP on a non-standard port, you'll need to find another deployment mechanism. My recommendation would be to try to update your REST client to not require a non-standard port.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I'm a bit confused by your last sentence, do you mean I should try to expose the port 80 or 443? But are these already bind by heroku?

Comment: Heroku will expose your app on ports 80 and 443 for you. The title of your question says that this is a REST service, so I assumed it was HTTP(S). If it's not, you'll need to find another solution entirely.