# A second node server (or port) won't start in production (Elastic Beanstalk)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Node/Angular app I'm trying to deploy. It uses two node servers: One to essentially serve the app; another to get data from an API, when a specific port is requested by the app, and store that data locally.

I've got it working perfectly on my own local machine. However, when I deploy to production environments -- either Heroku or AWS Elastic Beanstalk -- I find that the second script either won't run or won't start properly. The end result is, it doesn't get the data I need.

Here are the two scripts; they're both set to run in package.json under     *"start": "node main.js & node node-server.js"*

**main.js** (again, this one seems to be serving the app just fine):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

**node-server.js** (the one that doesn't seem to work; no data is gathered or populated in the app):

```
var http = require('http');
var port2 = 1234
var fs = require('fs');

//We need a function which handles requests and send response
function handleRequest(req, res) {
    request.get({
        url: 'http://sample-url.json',
        qs: {
            url: 'http://sampletool/pb/newsletter/?content=true'
        }
    }, function (err, result) {
        res.end(result.body);

        fs.writeFile('app/data.json', result.body, function (err) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            console.log('API data > data.json');
        });

    });
}

//Create a server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

//Lets start our server
server.listen(port2, function () {
    //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
    console.log("Server listening on: http://0.0.0.0:%d", port2);
});
```

Then, the main Angular app calls this port (http://0.0.0.0:1234) when the page is loaded, to request new data.

Elastic Beanstalk is using nginx, something I'm not super familiar with and that I don't have running on my local.

Is there something big I'm missing in configuring multiple node.js servers to be running on different ports in a production environment? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, cloud service providers typically allow the usage of only one port (which is dynamically and randomly assigned to the `PORT` environment variable) for an application to use from a node server. Read [this section](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers) from Heroku documentation to understand more about this.

This is why the main app (**main.js**) that uses `process.env.PORT` is working and the other app (**node-server.js**) that uses hard-coded `1234` is not.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107748/can-a-heroku-app-use-different-multiple-ports) has some pointers about the feasibility of multiple ports on Heroku (though, there is no good news there, I am afraid).

As how to go about fixing this, one thing that could be tried is to split this into two separate apps that are deployed separately with separate `package.json` etc.

Comment: Ah, thank you for this! I was pulling my hair out for way too long. I ended up creating my own ec2 Linux instance and setting it up so I can run the app there -- and all is well! So strange that elastic beanstalk in particular doesn't really explain this. Would have saved me a lot of headache.

Comment: @SaraCarothers - Glad to hear you have a working solution. And welcome to Stack Overflow! If the answer helped, please consider an up-vote and accepting it as detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I only have 8 rep so far so can't upvote yet (until I get to 15) - but I did check this as the answer.